# how to adjust # of ticks on Bokeh axis (labels are overlapping on small figures)

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, axis

I have a multi-figure Bokeh plot of vertically stacked & aligned figures.  Because I want to align the plots vertically, the y-axis labels are rotated to be vertical rather than horizontal.

In certain scenarios, Bokeh produces too many ticks, such that the tick labels overlap completely, making illegible.  Here is an example:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bp
import numpy as np

y = np.random.uniform(0, 300, 50)
x = np.arange(len(y))

bp.output_file("/tmp/test.html", "test")
plot = bp.figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200)
plot.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "12pt"
plot.yaxis.major_label_orientation = 'vertical'

plot.line (x,y)
bp.show(plot)
```

Short of making the renderer clever enough to produce fewer labels automatically, is there a way to indicate the # of labels to be placed on an axis?

It seems that the # of labels generated has to do with the range of the data, in terms of its affinity to a power of 10.

Comment: Hey man, very very late reply lol, but any chance you ever found a solution to this? Having a similar problem, posted on my profile if you could check it out. Thanks! @Jonathan Shore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like there is still no direct way to specify this. Please follow the related [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/665). This is a workaround:

```
from bokeh.models import SingleIntervalTicker, LinearAxis

plot = bp.figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200, x_axis_type=None)
ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=5, num_minor_ticks=10)
xaxis = LinearAxis(ticker=ticker)
plot.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')
```

[image]

You can control the number of tickets via the `interval` parameter in `SingleIntervalTicker`.

Comment: Hmm, actually the figures / layouts are created in a generic class separate from the rendering of data, so at that point I have no way of knowing the actual range of the data to use this trick.  That said, it does present a possible workaround, just not really one I can use in my situation, so will mark as answered.  Thanks

Answer (score 22):

You can control the number of ticks now with `desired_num_ticks` property. Look at the example from the bokeh docs (and this [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/2186)).

For example, in your case, something like this: `plot.yaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 10`.